# AWS Cron runs like crazy

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to add a cron job for my application on an AWS EB Env using into a cron.config file inside the .ebextensions folder.

The main issue is that the cron runs every second after I deploy the application.

I've user crontab.guru so I'm sure my cron was setup properly.

**Here's the cron job (located into .ebextensions/cron.config):**

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/slack_push_cron_job":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
          # CRON job to push to every day at 7am EST
          CRON_TZ="America/New_York"
          0 7 * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/index.php tasks index > /dev/null

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
```

I've tried many different setups but I'm not being able to fix this, I've also checked the logs, but couldn't find anything useful.

```
Mar 14 14:18:37 ip-172-31-17-65 crontab[18976]: (ec2-user) LIST (ec2-user)
Mar 14 14:18:56 ip-172-31-17-65 crontab[18997]: (ec2-user) LIST (ec2-user)
Mar 14 14:19:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[19009]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:19:16 ip-172-31-17-65 crontab[19038]: (ec2-user) BEGIN EDIT (ec2-user)
Mar 14 14:19:19 ip-172-31-17-65 crontab[19038]: (ec2-user) END EDIT (ec2-user)
Mar 14 14:19:40 ip-172-31-17-65 crontab[19066]: (root) LIST (root)
Mar 14 14:20:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[19092]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:21:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[19176]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:22:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[19259]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:23:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[19340]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:24:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[19423]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:25:01 ip-172-31-17-65 crond[1960]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/slack_push_cron_job)
Mar 14 14:25:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[19888]: (root) CMD (clearStaleLogPublishingRecords.py)
Mar 14 14:25:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[19887]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:26:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[19933]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:27:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[19968]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:28:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[19999]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:29:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[20239]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:30:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[20283]: (root) CMD (publishLogs.py --de-dupe --conf-path '/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/publishlogs.d/*' --location-prefix resources/environments/logs/publish/ --num-concurrent 2)
Mar 14 14:30:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[20284]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:31:01 ip-172-31-17-65 crond[1960]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/slack_push_cron_job)
Mar 14 14:31:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[20752]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:32:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[20795]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:33:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[20832]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 14 14:34:01 ip-172-31-17-65 CROND[20877]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/awslogs-nanny > /dev/null 2>&1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 0700 EDT is 1100 UTC, and logs from 1418-1434 aren't exactly illustrative of anything.

Comment: What does "run like crazy" mean? Why did you manually edit your crontab at 14:19?

Comment: @kichik it means that it runs every second. Although in the logs I saw just two runs